# Nuget - Declare NuGet PackageSource in packages.config

Tags: .net, nuget

Is there any way to declare in the file `packages.config` the private feed URL where to download the packages instead of using the `%AppData%\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config`?

What is the best practice to avoid to configure it manually trought Visual Studio or editing the `NuGet.config`?

Comment: Is there any reason you want to do this?

Comment: No you cannot specify this in the packages.config file. You can have a NuGet.Config file that is included with your solution. Does that help? NuGet will look in a few folders starting with the parent solution for the NuGet.Config file and working its way back to the root directory. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior

Comment: @JianpingLiu avoid that other people that pull the sources on their machine have to provide additional configuration on the environment

Comment: @MattWard It is definitely the solution I was expection about
Thank you

Comment: You can create a NuGet.config file in your solution folder to declare your private feed URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most of the users commented on my own question and as explained here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) on the official documentation:

> NuGet's behavior is driven by the accumulated settings in one or more
>   NuGet.Config (XML) files that can exist at project-, user-, and
>   computer-wide levels. A global NuGetDefaults.Config file also
>   specifically configures package sources. Settings apply to all
>   commands issued in the CLI, the Package Manager Console, and the
>   Package Manager UI.

So you can specify additional feeds (packageSources) by a NuGet.config file that exist at source code file level (ex .csproj).